# Customizing Subclipse's commit action to run sonar analysis

Tags: eclipse, svn, sonarqube, subclipse, visualsvn-server

We are using Eclipse Luna with Subclipse plugin to connect with SVN server (VisualSVN). The requirement is to modify the behaviour of commit action so that before check in , sonar analysis is carried out on all the files lined up for check in.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [SonarLint](http://sonarlint.org), which will run checks *as you code*.